# Stripe Strong Customer Authentication (SCA) and Expresso Store 1.6.4

Tags: expresso-store, stripe

I've looked around for answers to this but nothing's really come up. I understand that Stripe is implementing Strong Customer Authentication (SCA) in September 2019. I have a couple of legacy sites, that use much older versions of Expression Engine and Expresso Store. Can anyone provide some guidance on how I can continue to take payments on the site after September 2019? Upgrading the add-on isn't going to work in this case as everything was built such a long time ago, and it would mean a total rebuild.

Thanks!

Comment: Send a request to the ExpressoStore team, I've done the same and heard nothing :/ Will update here if I do.

Comment: Thanks @paulcripps I've reached out to the Expresso Store team too, if I get a reply I'll add it here

Comment: I'm in the same situation, did anyone get any updates? I'm not sure if it is an integration that Stripe needs to do or if it must be done on the Espresso side? Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to your Question, more of a comment but my rep isn't high enough yet :( however the guys at Foster Made who created Expresso Store posted this article which might be worth a read and could possibly help you. You can get in contact with them there too.

https://fostermade.co/blog/exp-resso-store-cartthrob-and-psd-2-strong-customer-authentication

Comment: Great find, thanks. That's the article the CartThrob team directed me to too.

Answer (score 0):

The Cartthrob team (responsible for Expresso Store) replied to me very kindly, saying that they are planning a release that supports SCA requirements. They'd be able to adapt my legacy site (which can't be upgraded) for a fee too, which I think is more than fair.

The team directed me to this link — https://fostermade.co/blog/exp-resso-store-cartthrob-and-psd-2-strong-customer-authentication which answers a lot of questions.